# What sort of attack URL is this?

Tags: php, http, website, exploit, attacks

I set up a website with my own custom PHP code. It appears that people from places like Ukraine are trying to hack it. They're trying a bunch of odd accesses, seemingly to detect what PHP files I've got.

They've discovered that I have PHP files called mail.php and sendmail.php, for instance.
They've tried a bunch of GET options like:

```
     http://mydomain.com/index.php?do=/user/register/
     http://mydomain.com/index.php?app=core&module=global§ion=login
     http://mydomain.com/index.php?act=Login&CODE=00
```

I suppose these all pertain to something like LiveJournal?

Here's what's odd, and the subject of my question. They're trying this URL:

```
     http://mydomain.com?3e3ea140
```

What kind of website is vulnerable to a 32-bit hex number?

Comment: It's not so much that a host is *vulnerable* to a string, it's that a compromised host may reply in a specific way to specific GETs. POSTs/GETs are frequently used for controlling an infected host. It could very well be a bot just checking to see if this host is already infected.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a "knock-knock" request, because it doesn't look like any common vulnerability. Please note, that script kiddies don't always know what they're doing.

Comment: Knock-knock? Is that the technical term for it?

Comment: Well, it's how we call it (checking if a host is up) in our company ;-)

Comment: +1 - "script kiddies don't always know what they're doing". That shatters my vision of the hackers out there being really talented, misunderstood geniuses like they show in the movies. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 I've tried watching those movies. They're horrible. But the comedies that make fun of geeks, like The IT Crowd, are very good.

Comment: WarGames (1983) and Hackers (1995) were pretty good ;-)

Comment: Hackers? I fell asleep. Anyway, since when do the secret service have time to pursue hackers, when they're knee-deep in hoes?

Comment: @Asker: Maybe FINESEC confused it with Sneakers (1992)?